# An exercise about Marcinkiewicz integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F$={$0$} $\bigcup$ {$\frac{1}{k}$:$k\ge2$} $\bigcup$ {$\frac{-1}{k}$:$k\ge2$} be a closed subset of $(-1,1)$.

For any $t\in(-1,1)$,define  the distance function $\delta(t) = inf_{p\in F}${$|t-p|$}.

For any $\lambda \gt 0$,consider the Marcinkiewicz integral

$$ M_{\lambda}(x)=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\delta^{\lambda}(t)}{|x-t|^{1+\lambda}}  dt$$

Is $M_{\lambda}(0)$ finite ?

I have no idea how to solve the question,can you give me some suggestion,thank you!!!

Comment: What is $\delta^\lambda$?

Comment: $\delta$ to the power of $\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

[Is the set $F$ make the $M_{\lambda}(0)$ finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080325/is-the-set-f-make-the-m-lambda0-finite)